# Unity: Siccity.GLTFUtility shader not loading in build

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader, gltf

I'm making a Unity desktop application for windows and in my app, 3D models of file type **glb** and **gltf** are loaded into the scene from the disk at runtime. These work fine in the Unity editor but when I build it, the models don't load in.

I used **Siccity.GLTFUtility** to load in these files.

Here is the Player.log error related to the issue (there are no other errors throughout the log file as far as I'm concerned):

```
ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: shader
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEngine.Material.CreateWithShader(UnityEngine.Material,UnityEngine.Shader)
  at UnityEngine.Material..ctor (UnityEngine.Shader shader) [0x00008] in <ed4b14358c3a426aacd38939413c3d3b>:0 
  at Siccity.GLTFUtility.GLTFMaterial+PbrMetalRoughness+<CreateMaterial>d__5.MoveNext () [0x0006a] in <a234369d3f4e4b83afe3dc4030317985>:0 
  at Siccity.GLTFUtility.GLTFMaterial+<CreateMaterial>d__14.MoveNext () [0x000b9] in <a234369d3f4e4b83afe3dc4030317985>:0 
  at Siccity.GLTFUtility.GLTFMaterial+ImportTask+<OnCoroutine>d__4.MoveNext () [0x00114] in <a234369d3f4e4b83afe3dc4030317985>:0 
  at Siccity.GLTFUtility.Importer+ImportTask`1[TReturn].RunSynchronously () [0x0001b] in <a234369d3f4e4b83afe3dc4030317985>:0 
  at Siccity.GLTFUtility.Importer.LoadInternal (Siccity.GLTFUtility.GLTFObject gltfObject, System.String filepath, System.Byte[] bytefile, System.Int64 binChunkStart, Siccity.GLTFUtility.ImportSettings importSettings, UnityEngine.AnimationClip[]& animations) [0x000ab] in <a234369d3f4e4b83afe3dc4030317985>:0 
  at Siccity.GLTFUtility.Importer.ImportGLB (System.String filepath, Siccity.GLTFUtility.ImportSettings importSettings, UnityEngine.AnimationClip[]& animations) [0x00012] in <a234369d3f4e4b83afe3dc4030317985>:0 
  at Siccity.GLTFUtility.Importer.LoadFromFile (System.String filepath, Siccity.GLTFUtility.ImportSettings importSettings, UnityEngine.AnimationClip[]& animations, Siccity.GLTFUtility.Format format) [0x00033] in <a234369d3f4e4b83afe3dc4030317985>:0 
  at Siccity.GLTFUtility.Importer.LoadFromFile (System.String filepath, Siccity.GLTFUtility.Format format) [0x00006] in <a234369d3f4e4b83afe3dc4030317985>:0 
  at MultiModelLoader+<DownloadAndSaveFile>d__44.MoveNext () [0x00159] in <d1494a091caf4b75869a10c4f73429a5>:0 
  at UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext (System.Collections.IEnumerator enumerator, System.IntPtr returnValueAddress) [0x00026] in <ed4b14358c3a426aacd38939413c3d3b>:0 
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:StartCoroutineManaged2(MonoBehaviour, IEnumerator)
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:StartCoroutine(IEnumerator)
<LoadFiles>d__42:MoveNext()
UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine:InvokeMoveNext(IEnumerator, IntPtr)
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:StartCoroutineManaged2(MonoBehaviour, IEnumerator)
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:StartCoroutine(IEnumerator)
MultiModelLoader:PaginateItems(String[])
MultiModelLoader:ReadData()
<Start>d__37:MoveNext()
UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine:InvokeMoveNext(IEnumerator, IntPtr)
```

Here's the main part of the C# code that loads the 3D models into the scene:

```
IEnumerator DownloadAndSaveFile(string fileId, Vector3 position)
    {
        string extension = items[fileId].ModelFileExtension;
        string fileName = fileId + "_model." + extension;
        string folderPath = modelPath + category + "/";
        string filePath = folderPath + fileName;

        // Check if the file already exists
        if (File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            CustomDebug("File " + fileName + " already exists in " + folderPath);
        }
        else
        {
            // Download the file from Firebase Storage and save it to local storage
            UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(storageUrl + "models%2F" + fileName + "?alt=media");
            www.downloadHandler = new DownloadHandlerFile(filePath);
            yield return www.SendWebRequest();

            if (www.result != UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
            {
                Debug.Log(www.error);
                yield break;
            }

            CustomDebug("File " + fileName + " downloaded and saved to " + folderPath);
        }

        // Load the GLTF file using the GLTFUtility library
        gltfObject = Importer.LoadFromFile(filePath);

        // Set the object's name to the file name (without extension)
        gltfObject.name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileId);

        // Set the parent object
        gltfObject.transform.SetParent(parentObject.transform);

        // Calculate the bounding box of the model before scaling
        Bounds preBounds = gltfObject.GetComponentInChildren<MeshRenderer>().bounds;

        // Calculate the scale factor needed to fit the bounding box within a desired size
        float desiredSize = 2f; // desired size in world units
        float scaleFactor = desiredSize / preBounds.size.magnitude;

        // Apply the scale factor to the model
        gltfObject.transform.localScale *= scaleFactor;

        // Add a BoxCollider to the object
        gltfObject.AddComponent<BoxCollider>();

        // Set the layer of the object to Realtime for realtime lighting to affect it
        int layerIndex = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Realtime");
        // Since some models contain child objects, it's required to set all objects to that layer to receive lighting
        SetLayerRecursively(gltfObject, layerIndex);
        gltfObject.layer = layerIndex;

        // Position the object in the scene as desired
        gltfObject.transform.position = position;

        // Add gravity to the objects and let it place itself on the surface
        gltfObject.AddComponent<Rigidbody>();
        gltfObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = false;
        gltfObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().useGravity = true;
    }
```

Since the above function is called using a *StartCoroutine* function, I also thought maybe doing the same thing using a multithreaded approach would work. But I tried it and it failed even in the editor. Here's how Siccity suggests in his github page:

```
// Single thread
using Siccity.GLTFUtility;

void ImportGLTF(string filepath) {
   GameObject result = Importer.LoadFromFile(filepath);
}
```

```
// Multithreaded
using Siccity.GLTFUtility;

void ImportGLTFAsync(string filepath) {
   Importer.ImportGLTFAsync(filepath, new ImportSettings(), OnFinishAsync);
}

void OnFinishAsync(GameObject result, AnimationClip[] animations) {
   Debug.Log("Finished importing " + result.name);
}
```

As the github page of the related gltf loader stated, I added each individual shader to *Always Included Shaders* but it still doesn't work.

Apart from that, I also tried enabling a few options randomly to see if any of it works.

[image]

- Tried setting **Instancing Variants** to **Keep All**.
- Pressed on **Save to asset...** and added that file to Preloaded Shaders as shown in the image.

[image]

- Tried changing the default **quality level** to Very Low.

[image]

- Disabled **Optimize Mesh Data**.

This is my very first Unity project and I'm doing it for my finals. I decided to ask this question here because I'm running out of time and options. Any help/suggestions on how to fix this would be very much appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It may be a little late to answer you now, but if your project uses the urp render pipeline you must add the corresponding shader of GLTFUtility in Graphic Settings and not just the built-in ones!

Comment: It is indeed a finished project but thank you! It could be helpful for someone who sees this or for a later project I do myself